# How to set an image as background for KinectTilebutton and make it hover during mouse movement?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

Hi I have a `Kinect` tile button with a `Background` image set as follows

```
<k:KinectTileButton Click="ClickEvent" Height="50" Width="50" Foreground="White" Content="Button">  
    <k:KinectTileButton.Template>  
        <ControlTemplate>  
            <Image Source="BackgroudImages\icon.png"></Image>  
        </ControlTemplate>  
    </k:KinectTileButton.Template>  
</k:KinectTileButton>
```

My `image.png` is also `50x50` pixels. But after I have set the `Background` `Image` I have lost the hover option when my mouse pointer moves over it. Can I make a button glow during hover while its `Background` is set?

If a `Button's background` is set can I write a text over the image? `Android` has this option of both setting `Background Image` for a `Button` and writing text over this `Background`.

Comment: use k:KinectTileButton.Background proerty to attach image at background

Comment: @Jodha can you please help me with the exact code? I am a beginner. Also, if I set the image as a background for a tilebutton, can I get that glow while hover? I am not getting that glow with the above code.

Answer (score 2):

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri("nosw.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
bi.EndInit();

var button = new KinectTileButton {
    Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
    Tag = lst[i],
    //Label = lst[i],
    Height = 200,
    Width = 250
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<k:KinectTileButton.Background>` in that you can supply the imagebrush. sample code below.

```
<k:KinectTileButton Click="ClickEvent" Height="50" Width="50" Foreground="White" Content="Button">
<k:KinectTileButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="BackgroudImages/icon.png"></ImageBrush>
</k:KinectTileButton.Background>
```